# Spring-mvc Dispatcher Servlet mapping giving 404 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I am following along with the Pluralsight "Introduction to Spring MVC 4" course, i have done the two previous requested courses as well (Intro to Spring and Intro to Spring MVC).

I am not using any XML configurations, it's purely Java/Annotation based. Using the XML Equivalent i can access the "/greeting.html" page with no issue. All other answers on the site involve adding mvc:annotation-driven or a different url-mapping such as "/" or "*.do", which has not helped solve my issue.

The index page is displaying upon server startup (localhost:8080), but displays a 404 for localhost:8080/greeting.html.

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Console log shows the following:

> 16:15:02.072 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet
>   with name 'eventTrackerDispatcherServlet' processing GET request for
>   [/greeting.html]
>
> 16:15:02.078 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI [/greeting.html] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'eventTrackerDispatcherServlet'
>
> 16:15:02.078 [http-nio-8080-exec-4]
>   DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully
>   completed request

Please advise what configuration i may have missed.

WebConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.pluralsight")
public class WebConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return resolver;
    }
}
```

WebAppInitializer.java

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("eventTrackerDispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("*.html");
    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight.WebConfig");

        return context;
    }
}
```

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World :)");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>${greeting}</h1>
    <br />
    <h4>This Thing On? :/</h4>
</body>
</html>
```

I have re-watched the video's to try find my mistake but haven't yet.
Many Thanks.

**Edit 1 -** Using XML Based Servlet Mapping, i can access the following page successfully: http://localhost:8080/greeting.html
I can access this page using the HelloController code as above in my original post. [Greeting.html page - Working with XML configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svNvv.jpg)

After converting my application **from XML based configuration to ONLY Java based configuration** is when i start receiving the 404 when accessing that page.

Comment: Where is `greetins.html` placed, directly in WebContent or WEB-INF ? Are you able to access your `index.jsp`, if yes then what is the URL?

Comment: @hagrawal The structure is as follows: /WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp and /WEB-INF/index.jsp. I can access index page via [link](localhost:8080) and [link](localhost:8080/index.jsp)

Comment: Where is your `greeting.html`, for which you are getting 404, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET)` Try replacing `/greeting` with `/greeting.html` here.

Comment: @hagrawal - There is no greeting.html page. The /greeting URL is mapped to the hello.jsp file through the HelloController. I have added the comparable XML configuration above.

Comment: But said - "but displays a 404 for localhost:8080/greeting.html" .. If that is not the case then you should try `but displays a 404 for localhost:8080/greeting`

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy - II have replaced it as suggested and it made no difference.

Comment: @hagrawal - I appreciate the effort you are making to help me - I am supposed to be accessing the Greeting page using that URL (/greeting.html) - With the equivalent XML config - i can access the page via (/greeting.html) as i am supposed to.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused in what exactly you want to do, with the usage of "supposed to" in your above comment, also whether things are working with your with annotation and not config, or both? You comment with "***Edit 1***" is also bit confusing to me.

Comment: @hagrawal - I apologize for my lack of clarity. I have ammended my "Edit 1" to hopefully clarify where my issue comes in. I created the application with XML configuration first, and it worked, when attempting to remove the XML based configuration and use only Java based configuration - my 404 issue started.

Comment: No need to apologize buddy. You need to have your web.xml configuration to configure your Spring's disptacher servlet in your web.xml (`<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>`), otherwise even if you have your `@controller` annotation it would not work.

Comment: @hagrawal - implementing the WebApplicationInitializer as we did above is a feature of Spring MVC 4 that is suppossed to negate that requirement. The instructor specifically Demo'd this to show it is possible, and his exact mirrored config works. I have completely re-written the project from scratch and re-gone through the videos and i still cant get that java configuration to work. Here is an example: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-xml-vs-java-config .... **Thank you once again for your advice and help so far.**

Comment: I have never tried or worked on this hybrid spring configuration but I had a quick look at the tutorial link you provided and here are my few tips - **(1.)** As per link, either you can register a class using `context.register(AppConfig.class);` or scan full package using `context.setConfigLocation("com.example.app.config");`. I see that you can using scan package configuration but specifying a class, so I think either you should use `context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight");` or `context.register("com.pluralsight.WebConfig.class");` or `context.register("WebConfig.class");`

Comment: **(2.)** I haven't checked the API for `addServlet` method as in this `container
          .addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));`, but are you sure that what you are using `""eventTrackerDispatcherServlet""` as in `servletContext.addServlet("eventTrackerDispatcherServlet", new DispatcherServlet(context));` is correct?

Comment: @hagrawal With regards to **(1)** I will have a proper look through this again with your recommendation and give it a try. **(2)** This first string "eventTrackerDispatcherServlet" is the name given to the servlet it creates, as far as i saw was any string, _but i will double check_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@hagrawal - I have managed to get the application working thanks to your comment:

> (1.) As per link, either you can register a class using
>   context.register(AppConfig.class); or scan full package using
>   context.setConfigLocation("com.example.app.config");. I see that you
>   can using scan package configuration but specifying a class, so I
>   think either you should use
>   context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight"); or
>   context.register("com.pluralsight.WebConfig.class"); or
>   context.register("WebConfig.class"); - **hagrawal**

The issue was with how my *AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext* was registering my "WebConfig" class in my WebAppInitializer Class. I changed from:

> context.setConfigLocation("com.pluralsight.WebConfig");

To This:

> context.register(com.pluralsight.WebConfig.class);

And the application now finds the correct mapping to respond with. This means my Application is working fully in Java code and has no Web.xml configured anymore! :)

*Many thanks for helping and suggesting that to me!*